# pygame equivalent of settimeout? (call function after x milliseconds?)

Tags: python, pygame

How would I execute some code after a set number of milliseconds?

I only want to execute it once.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the `pygame.time.set_timer(eventid, milliseconds)` function, which generates an event with id `eventid` on the event queue every `milliseconds` milliseconds, which you can then handle however you like. You can stop the event from being generated again by calling `pygame.time.set_timer(eventid, 0)`.

SDL has an `SDL_AddTimer` function that does exactly what you want -- you pass it a callback function to be executed after some delay, but from the documentation I can't really find the `pygame` equivalent.

For a python solution, you can use the [`threading.Timer`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) class.

Comment: what is sdl? and how would i implement it?

Comment: @maxhud SDL is the C library that `pygame` is built on. I was just saying this behavior exists in SDL but apparently not in `pygame`.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look into the module [sched — Event scheduler](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html). The examples in the link are pretty neat to get you started

Answer (score 1):

For python solution setTimeout equivalent would be:

```
    import threading

def set_timeout(func, sec):     
    t = None
    def func_wrapper():
        func()  
        t.cancel()
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()

    def hello():
       print "Hello, world!"

    set_timeout(hello, 0.1) # This is 0.1s = 100ms
```